# how to stop rabbitmq servers

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, pid

I am trying to start a node app and I think rabbitmq is getting in the way.

Similar to this thread: ["node with name "rabbit" already running", but also "unable to connect to node 'rabbit'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737754/node-with-name-rabbit-already-running-but-also-unable-to-connect-to-node?rq=1)

```
$ ps aux | grep erl
rabbitmq  1327  0.0  0.0   2376   300 ?        S    Dec13   0:00 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.8.5/bin/epmd -daemon
rabbitmq  1344  0.0  0.3  59560 14888 ?        Sl   Dec13   0:10 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.8.5/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A30 -P 1048576 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -noshell -noinput -sname rabbit@jasonshark -boot /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@jasonshark-plugins-expand/rabbit -kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] -sasl errlog_type error -sasl sasl_error_logger false -rabbit error_logger {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@jasonshark.log"} -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@jasonshark-sasl.log"} -os_mon start_cpu_sup true -os_mon start_disksup false -os_mon start_memsup false -mnesia dir "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@jasonshark"
rabbitmq  1700  0.0  0.0   2136   284 ?        Ss   Dec13   0:00 /usr/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.2.7/priv/bin/cpu_sup
1000     15564  0.0  0.0   4392   820 pts/1    S+   19:23   0:00 grep --color=auto erl
```

I know I need to run `kill -9 {pid of rabbitmq process}` now, but which number is the pid?

How do I stop everything to do with rabbitmq, I don't want it interfering with my node js

Comment: **Stop Rabbit** MQ : `sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl stop`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. First, try shutting RabbitMQ down gracefully with the init.d script `sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop`
2. If that doesn't work, use `ps -eaf | grep erl` to find the process and parent ids.  The third column in the output is the parent process ID.  Find the first ancestor of all the processes that is still the erlang process (not the shell script that started it) and kill that.  This should terminate the other sub processes.  If not, kill those manually.

Answer (score 9):

I just started using RabbitMQ today and learned that you can cleanly shutdown a `rabbitmq-server` process by using the command `rabbitmqctl stop`.

This may not apply to your situation since you don't seem to be the person who launched rabbitmq on your server in the first place but if you have `rabbitmqctl` in your path, you can try using it to attempt a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (on Linux), when stopping gracefully didn't:

```
sudo pkill beam.smp
```

where `beam.smp` is name of parent RabbitMQ process in most recent version.

Comment: this works for a few seconds and it comes right back.  rabbitmq is like a freaken virus.  it won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the thing that worked for me was:

```
service rabbitmq-server stop
```

You may also run:

```
service rabbitmq-server start
```

to start it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) in your system, then you could just

```
pgrep <proc_name>
```

It will output a list of pids you can use to kill them

Comment: sorry I'm a noob, what's proc_name for this case?

Comment: The process name: in your case `epmd` or `beam.smp` or `cpu_sup `.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `brew` when installing, you can use `brew services restart rabbitmq`, `brew services start rabbitmq`, `brew services stop rabbitmq`