# Remain the process if RabbitMQ stop.. is it normal?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

i have a question for rabbitmq

Below is a my process

1. installed RabbitMQ on my Windows10 Pro Linux Subsystem Ubuntu 18.04
2. $ sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
3. $ sudo service rabbitmq-server start
4. [after start, ubuntu process's status Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5mfn.png)
5. $ sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
6. [after stop, ubuntu process's status Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pk2F.png)

so, here is my question

1. why `/usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.2/bin/epmd -daemon` are remain ?
2. is it normal?
3. if it unnormal, what is solution?

i will watting your answer !

thanks for read !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal for `epmd` to continue running. You can read more about `epmd` [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html).

Please note that RabbitMQ has a native Windows installer and is not tested on WSL (and probably will never be).

Answer (score 0):

As @luke-bakken already answered, the problem is most probably caused by using rabbitmq in WSL instead of native one.

I also encountered same issue. My solution was first stopping the rabbitmq-server service, then stopping the local rabbitmq erlang node (not sure if this is required but somehow service rabbitmq-server stop did not stop this node) and finally killing all (one by one epmd deamons using epmd interactive options) . So I used following sequence:

1. `sudo service rabbitmq-server stop`
2. `sudo -u rabbitmqctl stop #not sure if this one is really required`
3. ```
   count=`ps -ef | grep epmd | wc -l`
   for x in {1..$count} ; do /usr/lib/erlang/erts-10.2.4/bin/epmd -kill ; done
   #this will try to kill epmd at least one time more than actual number of epmd started, however this extra epmd -kill call will not break anything, just not succeed.
   ```

Please note, that there are several other questions similar to this one on stackoverflow. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615765/how-to-stop-rabbitmq-servers) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737754/node-with-name-rabbit-already-running-but-also-unable-to-connect-to-node). Especially the first one contains some useful tips.

Also here is a list of manual pages worth to read :

1. [man rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html)
2. [man epmd](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html)